# How to match all groups before a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match the below pattern and get all match groups before `END`? (python regex)

```
string = "BEGIN AA 123 BB 222 END CC 456"
pattern = r"([A-Z]{2}\s\d{3})"
```

This returns three matches including `CC 456` but I only want the first two groups before the `END`

I tried using look ahead but that only returns second match group :(

Comment: Is this intended as a form of assembly processing? I'm not convinced that regex is the proper tool for this problem.

Comment: I understood you want [this](http://tpcg.io/BSfIMLx2). Yet you selected an answer that returns `"BEGIN AA 123 BB 222"`. Moreover, if the string were, say, `"BEGIN AA 123 BB 22 END CC 456"` the code at the link returns `['AA 123']` (which is what I understand you would want), whereas the selected answer returns `"BEGIN AA 123 BB 22"`. I don't understand why the latter is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not try to kill all birds with one stone. Sometimes regex is not the best tool. Split the string into two parts and apply regex pattern matching only to the first part.

```
first_part = string.split(" END ")[0]
```

Comment: Yes this is probably best, but regex works too: `([A-Z]{2}\s\d{3})(?=.*END)`

Comment: Doh - I had tried ([A-Z]{2}\s\d{3}).*(?=END) instead. Thank you both! You guys were so quick

Comment: You may wish to add word boundaries to avoid matching, for example, `"BEND"`: `(?=.*\bEND\b)`.